# jQuery validate single input and require two strings First and Last name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use a registration form that asks users to enter their full name into one input field. A php class then parses their first and last name and inserts to our db. I just found out our billing system doesn't like receiving just a first name so I have to validate the form field and make sure there are two strings entered. This is a fiddle of a basic input with validation but i'm not to good and writing a rule to check for two strings. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

**http://jsfiddle.net/peter/4X3mx/1/**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(e) {
        if (/\w+\s+\w+/.test($("#cname").val())) {
            alert("good");
        } else {
            alert("bad");
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YrFfG/

Comment: Thanks works like a charm, will accept the answer in a few minutes as soon as it lets me

Comment: @Anagio additionally you should look for the 'pattern' new attribute of the *input* element, this could avoid any script and be more reliable

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#cname').val().split(' ').length >= 2)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

client side :

```
if( input.value.split(' ').length == 2 ){
 //your code...
}
```

server side :

```
if( count( explode(' ', $_POST['name_field']) ) == 2 ){
 //your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/4X3mx/21/ for the solution. I am jQuery noob too so this might not be the best solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("twostring", function(value, element) { 
      return value.indexOf(' ') == -1? false: true; 
    }, jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value"));
  $("#commentForm").validate();
  $('#cname').rules("add", {required:true, minlength: 2, method: "twostring"});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

the joining ideas from JoseTomasTocino and spicavigo, can be better:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lastname", function(value, element) { 
    if (/\w+\s+\w+/.test(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}, jQuery.format("Please enter the correct value"));

$("#commentForm").validate();
$('#cname').rules("add", {required:true, minlength: 2, method: "lastname"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two words wouldn't necessarily work if the user has a two word last name like "Jeremy Von Morton" or something to that effect. Or if the label says "Full Name" the user might enter their middle name as well. I would display a note to the user that a first and last name is required. I would suggest splitting the name then combining the last two together afterwards in the case of a two or multi word last name. Then there is also the situation where the users first name has multiple words like "Mary Ann". This is usually why the name is split between multiple fields.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it:

*Note*: it will only allow **two** words, no more, no less.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "withTwoStrings",
    function(value, element) {
            howManyWords = value.trim();
            howManyWords = howManyWords.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' '); //remove extra spaces
            howManyWords = howManyWords.split(' ');

            if(howManyWords.length == 2){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    "Please Include First and Last Name. Thanks... :)"
);
```

And in the Rules object:

```
fieldName: {
      withTwoStrings: true,
},
```

*Note*: I don't know Regex, if somebody can do this with Regex, please let me know...